# Connect button to display data in a html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamically generated table that uses array of JS objects. I'm also adding a "View details" on each row. What I need is to be able to display data from the same array of objects in a different table.

I tried to add event listener to the buttons, but they either iterate through all of the rows or don't display anything

```js
function drawTable(tbody) {

  var tr, td;
  tbody = document.getElementById(tbody);

  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) // loop through data source
  {
    tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
    td.innerHTML = products[i].ProductName;
    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
    td.innerHTML = products[i].UnitsInStock;
    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);


    // View Details button
    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
    button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = ('View Details')
    td.appendChild(button)


  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table id="display-table" class="fl-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Units In Stock</th>
        <th>View Details</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-data">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<h2>Product Details</h2>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table class="fl-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Product Category</th>
        <th>Product Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-details">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't add event listeners to buttons in the table, add a single listener to the `tbody`, and track the row in the handler using row = `e.target.closest('tr')`, or if you've to get this work in older browsers too, `row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;`.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow :). I would recommend using for the for loop something simillar to this `for (product of products)`. When you call tbody you get it by the element id, but the id should be `table-data` or `table details` and not tbody. You can use `getElementsByTagName("tbody")`. For further information look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below `button.textContent = ('View Details')` add

```
button.onclick = (n=> event=> { 
  console.log('click on', products[n])  // you handler here
})(i); // set current loop "i" as parameter "n" value
```

we wrap function `event=>...` in `n=>...` to pass current `i` value - without this the `i` would be set always to last iteration value.

Comment: it worked out brilliantly, thanks a lot! in addition to your code, I added the following code so I can render what I needed from the data array `const productName = document.querySelector('#product-name');
        productName.textContent = products[n].ProductName;

        const productCategory = document.querySelector('#product-category'); 
        productCategory.textContent = products[n].Category.CategoryName;

        const productDescription = document.querySelector('#product-description');
        productDescription.textContent = products[n].Category.Description;`